# Notificar a cada 2 horas se houver novos dados inseridos

Tags: php, cron

Estou tentando criar um sistema para que o *Cron* execute um arquivo PHP a cada 2 horas, e verifique se houve inserção de algum registro em determinada tabela, caso haja novos registros, saber a quantidade total de novos registros nesse meio tempo.

A única abordagem que pensei foi fazer a consulta com um *COUNT*, salvar a quantidade de registros numa nova tabela e depois executar a consulta que irá enviar a notificação caso tenha novos registros.

A pergunta é: Essa abordagem é a ideal? Tem algo mais fácil ou até mais correto?

Comment: E se eu apagar um registo e depois criar um novo? O total será o mesmo. Nesse caso seria mais preciso verificar se existe um id maior que o anterior.

Comment: Humm, verdade, não havia pensado nessa hipótese. Vou ver o que faço, e obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua Abordagem funciona, mas se a tabela anterior tiver o algum campo datetime da hora de inserção da para você sempre que executar o cron pegar a ultima hora executada e consultar registros a partir daquele horario, se tiver registros depois da data da ultima execução, serão novos registros.
o cron salva um log sempre que é executado, da para pegar a data do log, e executar dali a diante!